# Mapview - Check the render method of 'App'

Tags: react-native

I'm building mapview in the app by using react native. but I got this error when I run the application:

> Check the render method of 'App'

What's wrong with this code? Sorry I'm new in react native.

App.js

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  MapView
} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
        style={styles.map}
          provider={null}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('newapp', () => App);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you created your app but your `MapView` import is not ok.
`MapView` is not a react-native sdk component.

You can either go to [MapView official git hub](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps), install it, and then

`import MapView from 'react-native-maps'`;

Or, you can use [Expo MapView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view) (if you created your app from the tool) and add this line:

`import { MapView } from 'expo';`

without installing anything else. The two versions are the same things.