# Check the render method of 'logo'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

I have the following code in the file where the **logo** is mentioned:

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Img from 'react-image';
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';
const paperStyle = {
  padding: 20,
  height: 6000,
  margin: 20,
  alignItems: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#ced7e5',
};

const Logo = () => <Img src={logo} />;

const Introduction = props => (
  <section id="home">
    <Paper style={paperStyle} zDepth={3}>
      <Logo />
      <h1 className="title">Welcome to this program</h1>
      <p className="intro">
        This program is to Render the challenge
      </p>
      <RaisedButton data-test-id="render-challenge" label="Render the Challenge" primary onClick={props.showChallenge} />
      <p>You might have noticed that clicking that button starts a long scroll. </p>
      <span style={{ fontSize: 60 }} role="img" aria-label="down-emoj" >â¬‡ï¸�</span>
    </Paper>
  </section>
);

export default Introduction;
```

After starting the yarn, I'm getting the below error:

> 

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> Check the render method of `Logo`.
> ▼ 30 stack frames were expanded.
> createFiberFromTypeAndProps

I have referred to the below links but could not relate them to my case.

- [Check the render method of 'SeekBar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888841/check-the-render-method-of-seekbar)
- [Check the render method of `component`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778450/check-the-render-method-of-component)
- [Mapview - Check the render method of 'App'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691807/mapview-check-the-render-method-of-app)

I'm not understanding if I should go and change something in the folder or the code.
Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If your const Logo is just a single img element just replace it where you are trying to call this Logo component. You could also try call it in your other component as. {Logo}. Or remove the arrow function so: const Logo = <img...>. Then in other component {Logo}

It also sounds like it could be a missing loader in your build. I would extend your webpack or CRA bundler to add a loader for png files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Img` is a named export, but you are importing it as default import.

change `import Img from 'react-image';` to `import { Img } from 'react-image';`

Comment: How did you understand if ```Img ``` was a named export?

Comment: Simple, checking it's documentation [react-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image#standalone-component-legacy)